# Блоки одинаковой высоты в соседних контейнерах

Tags: html, css

Добрый день!
Не могу придумать красивый и простой способ сделать следующее. Есть соседние контейнеры, которые разделены на блоки. Текст в блоках может быть разной длинны и, соответственно, высота блока будет меняться от контейнера к контейнеру, что отразится и на высоте самого контейнера. Вот макет:
[image: Макет]

Как сделать так, чтобы каждому блоку присваивалась максимальная высота блока его класса, т.е. для блока 2 во всех контейнерах высота равнялась максимальной из блока 2 контейнера 1, блока 2 контейнера 2, блока 2 контейнера 3?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: `<table>`? %)))

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант с использованием JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setEqualHeight(columns) {
        var tallestcolumn = 0;
        columns.each(
        function() {
            currentHeight = $(this).height();
            if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
             tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
            }
        }
        );
        columns.height(tallestcolumn);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
     setEqualHeight($(".columns > div"));
    });
</script>
```

Взято отсюда: http://webkab.ru/kak-sdelat-bloki-div-odinakovoj-vysoty-javascript/

А вот и без JS, если нужно: http://habrahabr.ru/post/148327/

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант подойдет?

html

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.conteiner{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;   
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
    border-spacing: 5px 0;
}
.conteiner .item-row{
    display: table-row;
    
}
.conteiner .item{
    width: 33.333%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;    
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}
.conteiner .item-row:nth-child(2) .item{
    border-top: none;    
    border-bottom: none;
   }
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="item">
            Добрый день! Не могу придумать красивый и простой способ сделать следующее. Есть соседние контейнеры, которые разделены на блоки. Текст в блоках может быть разной длинны и, соответственно, высота блока будет меняться от контейнера к контейнеру, что отразится и на высоте самого контейнера.
        </div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">
            Добрый день! Не могу придумать красивый и простой способ сделать следующее. Есть соседние контейнеры, которые разделены на блоки. Текст в блоках может быть разной длинны и, соответственно, высота блока будет меняться от контейнера к контейнеру, что отразится и на высоте самого контейнера.
        </div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">Добрый день! Не могу придумать красивый и простой способ сделать следующее. Есть соседние контейнеры, которые разделены на блоки. Текст в блоках может быть разной длинны и, соответственно, высота блока будет меняться от контейнера к контейнеру, что отразится и на высоте самого контейнера.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Варианты с таблицей (<table> и display:table) знаю. Прошу прощения что не написал ранее, но они мне не подходят да и для общего развития интересно узнать какой-либо иной способ, кроме вышеописанных...